# How to do 301 redirect http to https in apache when website listening port 80 and 443?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7, seo

I am using apache2.4 & configured website using drupal 7 . website is on port 80 & ssl is enable on port 443 . 
I have redirected homepage to https through websites admin login but on checking 301 redirection it says URLs are 
being redirected using 302 Temporary Redirection instead of this 301 Permanent Redirection should be used as this is 
considered SEO friendly redirection method. The only redirection i used so far is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but its not redirecting from http to https . I even tried following rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

can anyone help me how to redirect it permanently .

Answer (score 2):

Your Rules should redirect prmanently.
Check if your code is on top of the htaccess.

Also I think you want to check if the request is not on https and matches with your Domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

A better way than htaccess is to unsing the virtual hosts file i think - so the webserver doesn't need to reed the htaccess:
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thank you so much for replying, looks like i am nearby the solution. i tried your first rewrite rule that is RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off & next two lines . it is showing 301 for home page . But when i click further links, pages doesnot display & it gives me error saying too many redirect. please suggest

Comment: Hmm.. Check you other redirect Rules perhaps there is an redirect to http:// so it you got stuck in a redirect loop.